Linear Progamming solving (constrained) average-reward MDP would incur "reduciable" answer?
Let's first consider a simple, unconstrained example with two nodes {0,1}. Each node has two actions: {stay, transfer}, and all transition probabilities equal 1. Specifically, $P(0|0, stay) = 1,~P(1|0, transfer) = 1$. The reward corresponds to the state that $r(0) = 1,~r(1) = 0.5$. Following the linear programming steps outlined in https://web.stanford.edu/~lexing/opmdp.pdf, the solution indicates that once the system reaches state 0, it will never leave. This seems reasonable, but things become more weird in the constrained case.
Based on the above example, we introduce an additional cost on the states, where $c(0) = 1,~c(1)=0$, and the average cost constraint is $0.8$. Based on the original linear programming problem
$$max_{\mu^a\geq0} \sum_a (r^a)^T \mu^a~~s.t.\sum_a(I - (P^a)^T)\mu^a = 0,~\sum_{s,a}\mu^a_s = 1,$$
I add the additional constraint $\sum_a (c^a)^T \mu^a \leq 0.8$. The solution would be $\mu(0,transfer) = 0,~\mu(1,transfer)=0,~\mu(1,stay)=0.8,~\mu(1,stay)=0.2$ (I understand $\mu(s, a)$ as the joint probability). This solution seems "reducible" and impractical, as it never selects the transfer action in either state. My question is: Is this the correct way to solve a constrained average-reward/cost MDP using linear programming? If so, how should we interpret this solution?
